# Как скрыть получателей в рассылке?

Tags: php, рассылка

Как скрыть остальных получателей с txt файла?
в поле кому, отображаются все получатели, нужно что бы отображался только один.

index.php

```
<form action="send.php" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" placeholder="Введите сюда e-mail" value="<?php include ("maillist.txt"); ?>" name="e-mail">
    <input type="submit" id='mu_but' value="Нажмите, чтобы отправить письмо">
</form>
```

send.php

```
<?php
    //Получаем данные из глобальной переменной $_GET, так как мы передаем данные методом GET
    $email1 = $_GET['e-mail']; // Вытаскиваем почту в переменную
    $message = ' 
    <p>Текст письма</p> </br>
    <p>1-ая строчка </p> </br>
    <b style="color: #ff4200;">2-ая строчка </b> </br>
    '; // Формируем сообщение, отправляемое на почту
    $to = "$email1"; // Задаем получателя письма
    $from = "support@bla.ru"; // От кого пришло письмо
    $subject = "Тема"; // Задаем тему письма
    $headers = "From: $from\r\nReply-To: $from\r\nContent-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";

    if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) { // При помощи функции mail, отправляем сообщение, проверяя отправилось оно или нет
        echo "<p>Сообщение успешно отправлено</p>"; // Отправка успешна
    }
    else {
        echo "<p>Что-то пошло не так, как планировалось</p>"; // Письмо не отправилось
    }
?>
```

Comment: ну как так то... писал вроде нормально.. а отобразилось.. да ну вас

Comment: Отправляйте каждому получателю отдельное письмо.